# CS0201 C# Only assignment, call, increment, decrement, and new object expressions can be used as a statement

Tags: c#

i have a picturebox that changes the wordwrap property onclick for fastcoloredtextbox.

```
    private void pictureBox1_Click_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if(fastColoredTextBox1.WordWrap == true)
        {
            fastColoredTextBox1.WordWrap == false;
        }
        else if (fastColoredTextBox1.WordWrap == false)
        {
            fastColoredTextBox1.WordWrap == true;
        }
    }
```

However, when i run, i get the error CS0201 C# Only assignment, call, increment, decrement, and new object expressions can be used as a statement.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a typo, when *assigning* a value you only use a single `=`:

```
fastColoredTextBox1.WordWrap = false;
```

However, you can simplify your code down to this:

```
private void pictureBox1_Click_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    fastColoredTextBox1.WordWrap = !fastColoredTextBox1.WordWrap;
}
```

Comment: Oh thank you! I have to admit though, the errors are a bit confusing at times.

Answer (score 1):

You have  an error (or a typo) there. You meant:

```
fastColoredTextBox1.WordWrap = false
```

And

```
fastColoredTextBox1.WordWrap = true
```

Better than that, you should be doing just

```
fastColoredTextBox1.WordWrap = !fastColoredTextBox1.WordWrap
```

Instead of both ifs and assignments.

Comment: This works too. But i like DavidG's answer where he simplifies it.

Comment: Actually, both answers are the same. I was just editing it to include the tip when @DavidG answered. Concurrency issues...